# Node SQLite3 Changes not saved

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express

**Context**: I'm working on a Web App with Express Backend (Express & SQLite as Database)
**Problem**: If i make an API Call to Update some Rows in the Database, it (seems) to be working. If i query it, the Fields are Updated.
But if i stop/restart the Express Application, changes are reset.

**My SQLite Function**

```js
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";
import path from "path";
import { logger as _logger } from "../Shared";

let db: sqlite3.Database;

export const OpenDatabase = () => db = new sqlite3.Database(path.resolve(__dirname, 'cmsfm.sqlite3'), sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);
export const CloseDatabase = () => db.close();

export const SQLiteQuery = async (query: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    OpenDatabase();
    db.all(query, (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(row);
        }
    })
    CloseDatabase();
});
```

**Implementation (Get)**:

```js
const fahrzeug = await SQLiteQuery(
    `SELECT ${req.query.resultField} FROM fahrzeugdaten WHERE ${req.query.findBy} = "${req.query.find}"`
);
res.send(fahrzeug).status(200).end();
```

**Implementation (Update)**

```js
SQLiteQuery(
    `UPDATE fahrzeugdaten SET ${req.query.update} = "${req.query.value}" WHERE ${req.query.findBy} = "${req.query.find}"`
);
```

Anyone got a familiar Problem?

Comment: First install any tool to browse your SQLite database and use it to make sure that your updates are really stored. Then restart your application and make sure that this not changes your database. If everything is stored then check your Get implementation or client's cache or whatever.

Comment: @Serg, i've done this - the Data is not getting stored! But what could be the issue? I'm testing via Insomnia.

Comment: Check if you didn't update another database (wrong path) and check if you have permissions on database file. Also try to update all records - exclude `where` from your query - maybe you are trying to update a record which is not wxists.

Comment: There is only one SQLite Database File in that Directory. To make sure, i tried it on Gitpod.io . SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE Statements all work correctly, but somehow it doesn't save in the Database. Everytime i reload the Express Application, all changes get reset.

Comment: Again, are you sure you use this database file? So add record manually using database tool, then start your application and try to Get manually added record. Do you get this record via express app?

Comment: If you don’t get it via app possible reasons are: you open different database in your app or you app code recreate it at start. Of course if this is your complete code and you don’t use transactions which you forget to commit. Or maybe you restart app by reboot your OS which stores your file on a kind of ramfs.

Comment: I've now reworked my code to work with `better-sqlite3` instead of `node-sqlite3`. Tested it on multible Devices. I'm not using transactions (atm). When i make changes using SQLite3 Explorer to the Database File directly, it works and it gets saved. But when making changes via the API, changes revoked when stopping the API. Still the same issue.

Comment: What if you delete your database file, will API work or not?

Comment: i get an error that the specified Table does not exist.

Comment: Good. So we are sure that application opens needed file. So now what will be if you make changes in database with database tool not application, then reboot your computer and test if changes is valid after power cycle?

Comment: I've now done this, the Changes get saved when i do it via the Database tool.

Comment: Did you see these changes via backend application?

Comment: yes, the changes are then seen in the Backend and Frontend App

Comment: Try to make changes via API, stop application and check API updates with database tool not starting application.

Comment: Changes made from the API are not written to the Database when i checked it via the Database Tool.

Comment: This means that you have issue in your update query. First add console output with all properties of `req.query` object. Make sure that you have no `undefined` as well as you send correct datatypes which correspond to your database types. Also output to console the whole real `UPDATE` statement.